# How did `cl-flet` got circumvented?

Tags: lexical-scoping, let-binding, dynamic-scoping, cl, local-functions

I want to slightly alter the behavior of `counsel-fzf` by **locally** changing the definition of `counsel-fzf-action`, which activates in the end of the definition of the former. See the source code of `counsel-fzf` (please pay attention to the second last line):

```lisp
(defun counsel-fzf (&optional initial-input initial-directory fzf-prompt)
  (interactive
   (let ((fzf-basename (car (split-string counsel-fzf-cmd))))
     (list nil
           (when current-prefix-arg
             (counsel-read-directory-name (concat
                                           fzf-basename
                                           " in directory: "))))))
  (counsel-require-program counsel-fzf-cmd)
  (setq counsel--fzf-dir
        (or initial-directory
            (funcall counsel-fzf-dir-function)))
  (ivy-read (or fzf-prompt "fzf: ")
            #'counsel-fzf-function
            :initial-input initial-input
            :re-builder #'ivy--regex-fuzzy
            :dynamic-collection t
            :action #'counsel-fzf-action     ; <=== This is what I'll alter
            :caller 'counsel-fzf))
```

To slightly alter it, I tried nulling `#'counsel-fzf-action` locally by `cl-flet`.

```
(cl-flet ((counsel-fzf-action (x) nil))
    (counsel-fzf))
```

#### Question

However, the global function `counsel-fzf-action` is executed instead of the local one. This confuses me because shouldn't the local function gets favored first?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck here; this is the correct intended behavior.

`#'counsel-fzf-action` refers to the *global function definition* of `counsel-fzf-action`, *not* the local one.

The `cl-flet` binding is *local*, similar to the *lexical* binding of `let`:
unless the variable being bound is *dynamic* (i.e., defined using `defvar`), the nested functions do *not* see the binding.

Thus the only way out for you is to *modify* `counsel-fzf` to either accept the `action` argument or use a global `defvar` variable instead of `#'counsel-fzf-action`.

Comment: Another possibility is to advise `counsel-fzf` to change its behavior. See [chapter 13.11 Advising Emacs Lisp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: @sds I'm still confused. Normally, `#'XYZ` definitely should refer to the local function definition if any, instead of the global one. See for example: `(progn (defun fff () "global!") (funcall (cl-flet ((fff () "local!")) #'fff)))` which returns `"local!"`.

Comment: @Student: that's different: now `fff` is in scope.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for overriding functions, with many different behaviours.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550578/in-emacs-what-is-the-difference-between-cl-flet-and-cl-letf will probably resolve the confusion for you.

The first thing to know is that `cl-flet` is *not* the same thing as `flet`!

`flet` was dynamically scoped (and hence would have worked the way you expected), whereas `cl-flet` (and `cl-labels`) are lexically-scoped and won't.

The new way to mimic `flet` is to use `cl-letf` with a PLACE of `(symbol-function 'FUNC)`

See the linked Q&A for examples.

Comment: This makes sense! I did more research and wrote up a complete answer below. Please let me know if there's any misunderstanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank phils and sds for providing their answers. After
learning from them and a bit more research, I have come to an
understanding mostly from an excellently written article, *[Make
flet great again (by Chris
Wellons)](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/10/27/)*.

The article explained that `cl-flet` is lexically scoped (as in
`flet` in common lisp), and therefore in my use case

```
(cl-flet ((counsel-fzf-action (x) nil))
    (counsel-fzf))
```

the inner definition of `(counsel-fzf)` does not see the change
of `#'counsel-fzf-action`. What I intended to use, is the
dynamically scoped `flet` (but long *deprecated* in elisp). And
indeed that's what I wanted. However, `flet` is *deprecated* and
should not be used. No worries! The article also provides a
solution, and that's by using `cl-letf` (also mentioned by
phils), where `f` means "form" (as in the `f` in `setf`). So for
what I intended, I should use the following

```
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'counsel-fzf-action) 
           (lambda (x) nil)))
    (funcall #'counsel-fzf))
```

#### Summary

Currently in elisp (emacs 27.2),

- `cl-flet` is lexically scoped (as in the `flet` in common
  lisp), and behaves more sanely for byte compiled functions.
- `cl-letf` is dynamically scoped.
- `flet` is deprecated and should not be used. Instead one should
  use `cl-letf` if they need.